# How to remove default bootstrap effects appyid on button?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have taken a bootstrap button in my web page. When I click on that button it shows me an outline around the button indicating the focus on the button as shown in the image below:
[image]
.

But I want to remove that default effect.

Here is the code for this button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownBtn" style="background:white;border-top-width:5px;border-right-width:5px;border-bottom-width:5px;border-left-width:1px; border-color:#eee;height:42px;border-radius:0px;text-align:center;color:black; margin-right:20px;">Select<span class="caret"></span></button>
```

So please can anyone tell me any solution to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove dotted outline, do this but first remove that inline style and place it all in stylesheet.

```
button:focus, button:active {
    outline: none;
}
```